# Don't know why there are Total Freight Orders

Tags: simcity-2013

Every factories making their freight and sent it to commercial buildings.

But it is more effective when there is trade depots. Factories can send more freights and faster.

You can check the freight orders(commercial buildings order freights)at your city status bar.

But I don't understand why commercial buildings order freights.

It still fine if there are no industrial buildings.

Of course, industrial buildings create many jobs but nothing to do with commercial buildings.

Leak of Total Freight Orders demands industrial zones, and it is annoying.

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Hey Noname, Its fairly hard to figure out exactly what information you are looking for. If you could consider cleaning up the question a bit it would help us come up with an answer for you.

Comment: Commercial buildings order freights, and it causes demand for industrial buildings. But it's still fine if there is no industrial building, and my question is why there are freight orders exist.

Answer (score 1):

It may have been designed at one point in time that the industrial buildings would send goods to the commercial buildings in order for them to sell, but that is not the case. Commercial buildings are just a potential drop off point for goods but do not rely upon them at all. This is why you notice that you will sell more goods with a trade depot or port and the like.

At the end of the day the Freight Orders are just a way of tracking general industrial production when the goods are untyped. ie: They are not TVs or CPUs or any of the speciality type of goods, just the generic 'stuff' type.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to have industry without a place to receive freight shipments, the industry buildings will abandon.

If you try to have industry with only commercial buildings to receive freight shipments, the growth of industry is constrained by the growth of commercial.

> I don't understand why commercial buildings order freights

As of Update 6, freight that is delivered to a commercial building is converted into money, which helps the commercial building grow and keeps the building from abandoning.  It is possible to grow commercial buildings without freight, but freight will increase the speed of growth.